# Trouble with Asynchronous Execution and Closure in a Loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, closures

I'm trying to process an array of items asynchronously in JavaScript, but I'm running into issues with closures inside a loop. My goal is to perform an asynchronous operation on each item in the array, but the loop doesn't seem to capture each item correctly. Here's my code:

```
let items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('Processing item:', items[i]);
    }, 1000 * i);
}
```

When I run this, instead of logging each item, it prints **`undefined`** for each iteration. I'm not sure why it's not capturing the value of **`i`** at each iteration correctly. How can I modify this code to work as intended?